# how to loop through different numbers of elements in every loop?

Tags: python, loops, optimization, scipy, tree

I have a trinomial tree model with stock prices like the picture below. I want to write a loop to loop through elements in the column. I have flattened the nonzeros into a 1D array in the tree so later I can do scipy optimization. But after I flattened the data, I lost the column index(time steps). I only know the 1st element is from column 1, 2 to 4 from column 2, 5 to 13 from column 3.
But the following optimization procedure still requires loop by column.

How can I write a loop like this:
in the first loop, check 1st element(1st), second loop, next 3 elements(2nd to 4th), third loop: next 9 elements (5th to 13th)

[image: trinomial]

Comment: IMHO, you are using the wrong data structure for the job. Use a graph instead.

Comment: Later I still need it for optimization, the graph is for the illustration I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudocode will look something like this (assuming the array above is called `v`).

```
startIndex = 0
endIndex = 0
for i = 1 to len(v):
    v[i] // this is the i-th row in your screenshot above.
    v[i][startIndex:endIndex + 1] // slice v[i].

    // update start and end indices
    startIndex = endIndex + 1
    endIndex = endIndex + i * i
```